# Creating Tensorflow Dataset for mulitple time series

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, time-series, tensorflow-datasets

I have a multiple time series data that looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': np.tile(np.arange(5), 2),
                   'Object': np.concatenate([[i] * 5 for i in [1, 2]]),
                   'Feature1': np.random.randint(10, size=10),
                   'Feature2': np.random.randint(10, size=10)})

   Time  Object  Feature1  Feature2
0     0       1         3         3
1     1       1         9         2
2     2       1         6         6
3     3       1         4         0
4     4       1         7         7
5     0       2         4         8
6     1       2         3         7
7     2       2         1         1
8     3       2         7         5
9     4       2         1         7
```

where each object (1 and 2) has its own data (about 2000 objects in real data). I would like to feed this data chunkwise into RNN/LSTM using `tf.data.Dataset.window` in a way that different objects data don't come in one window like in this example:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df)

for w in dataset.window(3, shift=1, drop_remainder=True):
  print(list(w.as_numpy_iterator()))
```

Output:

```
[array([0, 1, 3, 3]), array([1, 1, 9, 2]), array([2, 1, 6, 6])]
[array([1, 1, 9, 2]), array([2, 1, 6, 6]), array([3, 1, 4, 0])]
[array([2, 1, 6, 6]), array([3, 1, 4, 0]), array([4, 1, 7, 7])]
[array([3, 1, 4, 0]), array([4, 1, 7, 7]), array([0, 2, 4, 8])] # Mixed data from both objects
[array([4, 1, 7, 7]), array([0, 2, 4, 8]), array([1, 2, 3, 7])] # Mixed data from both objects
[array([0, 2, 4, 8]), array([1, 2, 3, 7]), array([2, 2, 1, 1])]
[array([1, 2, 3, 7]), array([2, 2, 1, 1]), array([3, 2, 7, 5])]
[array([2, 2, 1, 1]), array([3, 2, 7, 5]), array([4, 2, 1, 7])]
```

Expected output:

```
[array([0, 1, 3, 3]), array([1, 1, 9, 2]), array([2, 1, 6, 6])]
[array([1, 1, 9, 2]), array([2, 1, 6, 6]), array([3, 1, 4, 0])]
[array([2, 1, 6, 6]), array([3, 1, 4, 0]), array([4, 1, 7, 7])]
[array([0, 2, 4, 8]), array([1, 2, 3, 7]), array([2, 2, 1, 1])]
[array([1, 2, 3, 7]), array([2, 2, 1, 1]), array([3, 2, 7, 5])]
[array([2, 2, 1, 1]), array([3, 2, 7, 5]), array([4, 2, 1, 7])]
```

Maybe there is another way to do it. The main requirement that my model should see that non-mixed data chunks come from different objects (maybe via embedding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, maybe just create two separate dataframes and then concatenate after windowing. That way, you will not have any overlapping:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': np.tile(np.arange(5), 2),
                   'Object': np.concatenate([[i] * 5 for i in [1, 2]]),
                   'Feature1': np.random.randint(10, size=10),
                   'Feature2': np.random.randint(10, size=10)})

df1 = df[df['Object'] == 1]
df2 = df[df['Object'] == 2]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df1).window(3, shift=1, drop_remainder=True).concatenate(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df2).window(3, shift=1, drop_remainder=True))

for w in dataset:
  print(list(w.as_numpy_iterator()))
```

```
[array([0, 1, 3, 3]), array([1, 1, 9, 2]), array([2, 1, 6, 6])]
[array([1, 1, 9, 2]), array([2, 1, 6, 6]), array([3, 1, 4, 0])]
[array([2, 1, 6, 6]), array([3, 1, 4, 0]), array([4, 1, 7, 7])]
[array([0, 2, 4, 8]), array([1, 2, 3, 7]), array([2, 2, 1, 1])]
[array([1, 2, 3, 7]), array([2, 2, 1, 1]), array([3, 2, 7, 5])]
[array([2, 2, 1, 1]), array([3, 2, 7, 5]), array([4, 2, 1, 7])]
```

**Update 1**:

Another approach would be to use `tf.data.Dataset.filter` like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': np.tile(np.arange(5), 2),
                   'Object': np.concatenate([[i] * 5 for i in [1, 2]]),
                   'Feature1': np.random.randint(10, size=10),
                   'Feature2': np.random.randint(10, size=10)})

objects = df['Object'].unique()
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df)
new_dataset = None

for o in objects:
  temp_dataset = dataset.filter(lambda x: tf.math.equal(x[1], tf.constant(o))).window(3, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
  if new_dataset:
    new_dataset = new_dataset.concatenate(temp_dataset)
  else:
    new_dataset = temp_dataset

for w in new_dataset:
  print(list(w.as_numpy_iterator()))
```

**Update 2**:
Yet another option would be to exclude / drop overlapping sequences. This way you can flexibly decide what to do with the overlaps:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': np.tile(np.arange(5), 2),
                   'Object': np.concatenate([[i] * 5 for i in [1, 2]]),
                   'Feature1': np.random.randint(10, size=10),
                   'Feature2': np.random.randint(10, size=10)})

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df).window(3, shift=1, drop_remainder=True).flat_map(lambda x: x.batch(3)).filter(lambda y: tf.reduce_all(tf.unique(y[..., 1])[1] == 0))

for w in dataset:
  print(w)
```

Comment: Good idea! I have updated my question and adjusted your answer. I have about 2000 different objects, and it looks like I need to write a lot of code.

Comment: It works. I was looking for more ways to do it.

Comment: I was also wondering if there are other options

Comment: Maybe It's a not good Idea to do such training with multiple instances and no one needs this feature.

Answer (score 0):

We can also avoid TensorFlow `filter` function in the answer from @AloneTogeher and use Pandas `groupby` instead:

```
ds = None

for _, df_ in df.groupby('Object'):
  ds_temp = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df_).window(3, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
  if not ds:
    ds = ds_temp
  else:
    ds = ds.concatenate(ds_temp)
```